# How to check equality of reversed comparator and original?

Tags: java, equals, reverse, comparator

Pre-TL;DR: Need to see if a comparator is an instance of (or equal to) another comparator, even if it is reversed.

Hello, I think this problem is very simple but I am just thinking too much into it.
I have a program that allows a user to sort lists by different comparators.  The user can choose ascending or descending order.  Since comparators are by default in ascending order, all I do to achieve descending order is create a new reversed comparator:

```
Comparator newReversedCMP = Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator originalComp)
```

Another part of the program saves the last comparator used so that the user can sort or view the last comparator used.  Let's say I have comparators dealing with names and salaries and a method that returns what it deals with, for example:

```
if (lastCMPUsed.equals(new NameComparator()){
    return "Name";
}
if (lastCMPUsed.equals(new SalaryComparator()){
    return "Salary";
}
```

Sorry for the long intro but my issue is that I also want to return "Name" or "Salary" even if it's a reverse of the original Name or Salary comparator.  If lastCMPUsed is a reversedOrder CMP, then it does not find them equal.

I have tried this but with no success:

`//lastCMPUsed = Collections.reversedOrder(new NameComparator());
if (lastCMPUsed.equals(Collections.reverseOrder(new NameComparator())
    return "Name";`

This does not return "Name" and sees them as not equal.
My equals method in each comparator is a simple instanceof check.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Well, they're fundamentally not the same comparator, so of course `equals` won't work.  Logic like this seems like an iffy design, though; why can't you store the string name separately?

Comment: Why will you just create a new Object to check? why not use the class property? if(lastCMPUser.getClass().equals(NameComparator.class) or even instanceof

Comment: I jumped the gun, while trying to come up with sample code for this question I actually fixed my issue.  I might be deleting this question. 
if (lastCMPUsed.equals(Collections.reverseOrder(new NameComparator())     return "Name";

This actually works if lastCMPUsed is a reverse of NameComparator

Comment: You shouldn't use `equals` in the way you've described. It breaks the contract of [`Comparator#equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), which should only return true if the ordering is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need some particular definition of equality besides one defined by [the supertype](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), you should write a class structure that will properly do this for you.

For example:

```
public abstract class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {
    private final boolean isReversed;

    private PersonComparator(boolean isReversed) {
        this.isReversed = isReversed;
    }

    public boolean isReversed() {
        return isReversed;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Person lhs, Person rhs) {
        return isReversed ? compareImpl(rhs, lhs) : compareImpl(lhs, rhs);
    }

    public abstract String getComparison();
    protected abstract int compareImpl(Person lhs, Person rhs);

    public static final class Name extends PersonComparator {
        private Name(boolean isReversed) { super(isReversed); }
        @Override
        protected int compareImpl(Person lhs, Person rhs) {
            return lhs.getName().compareTo(rhs.getName());
        }
        @Override
        public String getComparison() {
            return "Name";
        }
    }

    public static final Name NAME         = new Name(false);
    public static final Name NAME_REVERSE = new Name(true);
}
```

The equality here is that:

```
NAME.getClass() == NAME_REVERSE.getClass()    // true
```

```
NAME instanceof PersonComparator.Name         //
    &&                                        // true
NAME_REVERSE instanceof PersonComparator.Name //
```

```
NAME == NAME_REVERSE                          // false
```

```
NAME.equals(NAME_REVERSE);                    // false
```

```
NAME.getComparison()                          //
    .equals(NAME_REVERSE.getComparison())     // true
```

Note that I did not need to override `equals` and `hashCode`, because there is only a single instance of each possible Comparator.